# General Maven bugginess

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

So I'm finding that the more I use Maven, the buggier I'm finding it to be, especially when building the same project using different Maven versions. Is this to be expected?

A couple of examples:

I have a .ear I'm deploying to JBoss. As I'm bringing in wsdls, xsds and generated classes brought in on the class path, I'm bring the .jar in as a dependency then unpacking it into the .ear. To do this I'm using the unpack dependencies goal. Looks something like this...

```
<plugin>              
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-wsimport</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>url.projectName</includeGroupIds>
                        <includeArtifactIds>projectName-wsimport</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using Maven 3.0.3 (Which is what the project was originally built in), this works fine. Switch over to Maven 2.0.9 and all of a sudden it doesn't. On the Maven site it says this plugin has been supported since version 1.0, so why isn't it working?

In the same vein, but vice versa, when I'm trying to do a maven release of this project, using Maven 2.0.9 will prepare and perform correctly, however 3.0.3 doesn't copy across certain files when tagging a version in SVN.

Anyone else finding errors like this when switching between versions of Maven to build projects?

Comment: Please open separate questions for your separate issues. Also bear in mind that you're using different major release , 2.x versus 3.x . Some differences in behaviour are expected. Nevermind the fact that Maven 2.0.9 was released _four years_ ago .

Comment: Maven 2.0.9 shouldn't be used any more. If someone has to stick with Maven 2.0 it should be 2.0.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it looks like you didn't understand the maven way of doing things like an ear, cause within a EAR you have to add the dependencies which should be put into the EAR not via the dependency-plugin you have to use them as dependencies instead.

for Example:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>webgui</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>service</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

but the better approach is to use the correct configuration for the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html).

Based on the information you gave i would have expected to have a multi-module build which contains your different modules (like web-part, wsdl-part etc.) which will be packaged into an EAR. This would have resulted into a structure like the following:

```
   +-- root
        +-- pom.xml 
        +-- war
             +-- pom.xml 
        +-- wsdl
             +-- pom.xml 
        +-- ...
        +-- ejb
             +-- pom.xml 
        +-- ear 
             +-- pom.xml
```

Furthermore it looks like you need to look into the orginization of projects like multi-module projects. Here is an [example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee) of such kind. The [documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/Books/Maven-The-Complete-Reference) about Maven is a good way to start with and last but not least [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/index.php/Support/Books/Maven-By-Example).

About your point of buggines i can't acknowledge this, cause i'm working a long time with Maven in really large project (100 modules +)...Furthermore i would like to know where it's stated that this plugin works with version 1.0.

Despite the fact that it doesn't looke like that you read the release notes. There is large number of differences between the Maven versions in particular between Maven 2.0.X, 2.2.X and 3.0.X ..If you really need to run your build with differernt Maven version like 2.0, 2.2, and 3.0. This can be done and is working, but there are some drawbacks based on the technical detail in particular between 2.2.X and 3.0.X (reporting are). I would suggest to use only one Maven version to build your artifacts (currently 3.0.3/3.0.4). An other hint is that a Maven build which works for Maven 2/3 never will run with Maven 1, cause the POM has been changed dramatically.

Comment: Good answer, however I do think the issue here is why it was building in one version of Maven and not the other. In a perfect world I would be using one version of Maven, but I have inherited these projects that have been built in different versions and have to deal with them. As such, I don't think Maven's backward compatibility support is any good at all, and as such renders the concept of a 'pom' kind of redundant in the wider sense.

Comment: For example, if you found a project in .svn that you had to build but had no idea of what version of maven was used to originally build it, are you supposed to guess? The pom becomes useless in this context, as you need to know exactly what version of Maven was originally used to build the project, lest you start running into the issues I have.

Comment: Not really, cause the POM has a modelVersion which gives a small hint...in this case it must be at least Maven 2, cause Maven 1 has modelVersion 3. Furthermore i would use Maven 3. If i have to stick with Maven 2.0 i would use the newest 2.0.11 (AFAIK)..One other hint could be the plugin versions which have been defined in the pom which can give me an other hint to which particular version i have to go with.

Comment: The compatibility between Maven 2.2.1 and Maven 3.0.X is very good. Cause i'm testing many of my projects for my clients with both version, cause they don't like to upgrade but this is a different story. And the differences can simply be solved by a profile which states the differences in site generation.

Comment: OK, I'm just going to have to accept the non backwards compatibility issue, I guess. As I said, I would upgrade to Maven 3, but I'm finding the release prepare plugin is broken when it tags versions in svn. Don't really have the time to sit down and find out why, all help was appreciated.

Comment: The best thing is to open a new question for the problem with the release plugin and than i can help there.